# Brouwer's fixed point theorem $n=1$ case

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I have read a sketch of the proof for Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, i.e. that every continuous $f:\mathbb{D}^n\to\mathbb{D}^n$ has a fixed-point ($n\ge1$).

The idea is to construct a retract $r:\mathbb{D}^n\to\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ such that $r\circ i=id_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$. Taking $H_{n-1}$ yields the contradiction $[\mathbb{Z}\to 0\to\mathbb{Z}]=id_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

But as far as I see this only works for $n>1$, not for $n=1$, since $H_0(\mathbb{D}^1)=\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$.

So what can I do in the $n=1$ case?

Comment: There still does not exist a retract $[-1,1]\to \{-1,1\}$. Or use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Use reduced homology $\tilde H_0$ rather than $H_0$ itself.

Comment: Is $\tilde{H}_{n-1}$ still a covariant functor?

Comment: Well yes, it is! But what is $\tilde{H}_0(\mathbb{S}^0)$?

Comment: Are you asking how to show that a continuous function $f:[-1,1] \to [-1,1]$ has a fixed point?

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^0$ consists of two points, so $\tilde{H}_0 (\mathbb{S}^0) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. And $\mathbb{D}^1$ is connected, thus $\tilde{H}_0 (\mathbb{D}^1) = 0$.

Comment: May you please give further details to $\tilde{H}_0(S^1)=Z$?

Comment: @user114179 Do you mean $\mathbb{S}^0$? For $\mathbb{S}^1$, the group $\tilde{H}_0$ is trivial, as $\mathbb{S}^1$ is connected. For details, you should know that $H_0$ is generated by the connected components, and $H_0 \cong \tilde{H}_0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically just expanding on von Eitzen's comment here if you don't see it immediately.

For $n=1$, $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ and $f$ is continuous.

Define $g:[-1,1]\rightarrow[-2,2]$ such that $g=f(x)-x$. Note that $g$ is also continuous.

Now if either $g(1)$ or $g(-1)$ is equal to zero, we are done.

If not, $g(-1)<0$ and $g(1)>0$.

By the intermediate value theorem, $\exists c\in (-1,1)$ such that $g(c)=0$.

$g(c)=0\implies f(x)=x$.